# Magento 2 : Pass argument/variable in component js

Tags: magento2.2, component

I am using Magento2.2 . I want to pass variable in component JS from phtml file on frontend but don't know how ? I am using following code

```
<div id="product-custom-info" data-bind="scope: 'custom-scope'">
    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
    <script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
      "#product-custom-info": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
            "components":{
              "custom-scope":{
                "component":"Namespace_Modulename/js/customjs"
              }
            }
          }
      }
    }
    </script>

</div>
```

**Namespace/Modulename/view/frontend/template/web/js/customjs.js**

```
define([
'jquery',
'ko',
'uiComponent',
'domReady!',
], function ($, ko, component) {
    'use strict';
    return component.extend(function(config){      
      console.log(config);
      });
})
```

Please help me solve this problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you need to define your template in the JS file and pass variables from phtml.

In js:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'ko',
    'uiComponent',
    'domReady!',
], function ($, ko, component) {
    'use strict';
    return component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'Vendor_Module/template'
        },
        productInfo: window.customInfo

        initialize: function () {
            //init function code here
        }
    });
})
```

and in `PHTML`:

```
<div id="product-custom-info" data-bind="scope: 'custom-scope'">
    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
    <script>
        window.customInfo = 'variable';
    </script>
    <script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
      "#product-custom-info": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
            "components":{
              "custom-scope":{
                "component":"Namespace_Modulename/js/customjs"
              }
            }
          }
      }
    }
    </script>

</div>
```

If you have the information from backend block function , something like an array you can do as follows

```
<div id="product-custom-info" data-bind="scope: 'custom-scope'">
    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
    <script>
        window.configs = <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo \Zend_Json::encode($block->getConfig()); ?>;
    </script>
    <script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
      "#product-custom-info": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
            "components":{
              "custom-scope":{
                "component":"Namespace_Modulename/js/customjs"
              }
            }
          }
      }
    }
    </script>
</div>
```

And in JS

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'ko',
    'uiComponent',
    'domReady!',
], function ($, ko, component) {
    'use strict';
    return component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'Vendor_Module/template'
        },
        productInfo: window.customInfo.**keyName**

        initialize: function () {
            //init function code here
        }
    });
})
```

where **keyName** should be the array key from the block

**UPDATE**
You can do without `window....` variables something like this:

```
return Component.extend({

        initialize: function (config) {
            var paramValue = config.parameter;
        }
    });
```

and in your PHTML:

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
    "#some-element-id": {
        "Namespace_Module/js/jsfilename": {"parameter":"value"} 
    } 
} 
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks @Vlad. But in case multiple times render same html on same page. It always picking one of them  either 1st or  last.

Comment: it that case I would recomand in `XML` setting an `ID_Modifier` and make the init dependent on that maybe add that modifiere as an `sufix` for the variables

Comment: Can you please add sample code ?

Comment: Is there any way to get the parameter without using `window object`

Comment: @zedBlackbeard  updated answer

Answer (score 12):

The bellow work as a treat for me:

```
<div id="product-custom-info" data-bind="scope: 'custom-scope'">
<!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
  "#product-custom-info": {
        "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
        "components":{
          "custom-scope":{
            "component":"Namespace_Modulename/js/customjs",
            "myVar" : "My Value"
          }
        }
      }
  }
}
</script>
```

Then in customjs:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'ko',
    'uiComponent',
    'domReady!',
], function ($, ko, component) {
        'use strict';
        return component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'Vendor_Module/template'
        },

        initialize: function (config) {
            console.log(config.myVar) //logs My Value
        }
    });
});
```